# Why HashMap's get's argument is Object and not type of the key?

Tags: java

I am woindering why this method

```
public V get(Object key) {
```

is not

```
public V get(K key) {
```

Thank you

Comment: because object is parent class and can all any type of onbject

Answer (score 1):

The key may not strictly be of the type `K`. As long as the `equals` method contract is followed, any `Object` could be the key:

> More formally, if this map contains a mapping from a key `k` to a value `v` such that (`key==null ? k==null : key.equals(k)`), then this method returns v; otherwise it returns null. (There can be at most one such mapping.)